# How to setup sublime text editor to show any syntax error before executing the code?

Tags: syntax-error, sublimetext, precompile

I wanted to know that how can you setup sublime text editor to show any syntax error before executing the code as in visual studio code it shows a red line if there is any syntax error even before executing the code.

Answer (score 1):

For displaying syntax issues in Sublime Text, check out https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter for that functionality.

First install Package Control from within Sublime Test by opening the Command Palette:

Win/Linux: `ctrl+shift+p`, Mac: `cmd+shift+p` (From inside Sublime Text)

Then type: `Install Package Control` in the Command Palette and press Enter.
(Or you can access from the Top Menu with `Tools` -> `Package Control`.)

Then install `SublimeLinter` from within the Package Control of Sublime Text.

Then make sure to change default settings from Package Control:

- `SublimeLinter: Show Errors on Save`

---

**Reference Documentation:**

- https://www.sublimelinter.com/en/stable/
- https://packagecontrol.io/installation
- https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-catch-your-errors-in-sublime-text-3
- https://www.sublimelinter.com/en/v3.10.10/lint_modes.html#the-modes
- https://www.sublimelinter.com/en/v3.10.10/lint_modes.html#showing-errors-on-save